# browser helper object in c++

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, browser, bho

i am new to win api ,this is what i was using in my code

`SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE, OnDocumentComplete)`

this is perfectly working

**note** :

`OnDocumentComplete`-function pointer

`DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE` --display id (call the function pointed by function pointer when this event occur)

i just tried the below one which will call the event on changing status bar of browser hide or appear but its not working .

`SINK_ENTRY_EX(1, DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, DISPID_ONSTATUSBAR,OnDocumentComplete)`

can any body tell me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input parameters of the OnDocumentComplete and OnStatusBar events are different.  You can't use the same function for both events.

Answer (score 0):

Remy your correct i got the below link which helps me to find what function signature to be used for which event not much detail but signature of function

http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=OqcwL0bIw3vC9ejiHfbJrKc1E_M&cid=0W4KUpSYxGo&s=&browser=Default#L0